# Removing XSS Script in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, xss

I was trying to test my WordPress website security which right now I am baffled. In a form, I entered `<script>alert('XSS Expoit worked');</script>` in the input. After submitting the form, a pop-up box appeared on the next page. This means my form is not yet secured. But that's not the problem.

Let me explain first, the submission of that XSS script will be update in the user by `update_user_meta()` and should be available on the `usermeta` table in the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_userinfo'])) {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
     if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['peoplesweep_user_form'],'peoplesweep_form_submit')){
            wp_die('Our Site is protected!!');
        }
        else{
            $nric = $_POST['nric'];
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'nric', $nric );
            wp_redirect(get_permalink('next_page')); // next page after submission success
        }
}
```

The problem here is, I did not find the script in the table & every time I logout & login then skip to the `next_page`, the script still pops out. **I need to know where it was stored so that I can delete them**.

Any ideas where the script stored? And/Or how am I going to review any changes in the database????

Comment: did you search the db  for just `"XSS Expoit worked"` because the special chars will be encoded or are you using a caching plugin ?

Comment: @TarranJones yeah I did search for that string but before that, I searched for the rows first which contain the `nric` value because that `XSS Expoit worked` must also be in that row as it is submitted from input field with the name of `nric`... But that row didn't exist even when I submit multiple times! Catching plugin? I don't know about that, but I do use NinjaFirewall plugin, it helps prevent guests and registered users from doing malicious things... However, it does not prevent the admin from doing self-destruct things such I am doing now...

Comment: _"This means my form is not yet secured"_ - no; it means the data was not handled properly at the moment of output. / Using phpMyAdmin you can easily do a search over all tables and all columns.

Comment: @CBroe So what are you suggesting??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking `wp_usermeta` table?
You can refer to [this link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) to get a really helpful and detailed description of Wordpress database structure.